# Emmet for VS Code with Vue, 'wrap with abbreviation' removes indentation

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, emmet, vetur

Emmet's 'wrap with abbreviation' command in VSCode with Vue.js in template is misbehaving for me.

Wrapping a code block inside any element (`div` in this example) is causing all indentation inside that code block to be removed.

I've tried adjusting various settings but can't figure out what's causing it to format like this!

Before:
[image: Before:]

After: 
[image: After:]

My settings.json file looks like so:

```
{
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "vetur.validation.template": false,
    "vetur.completion.useScaffoldSnippets": false,
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            "attr_quotes": "single",
            "indent": true,
            "tag_nl": true
        },
        "vue-html": "html",
        "vue": "html"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "sync.gist": "bcd2ebd3919d3e74184418b308e3aa85",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "none",
    "vetur.complete": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "chalice-icon-theme",
    "material-icon-theme.saturation": 0.5,
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', 'Courier New', monospace",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#000",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#ffff73"
    },
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "indent",
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "markdown"
    ],
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    },
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "",
    "vetur.completion.scaffoldSnippetSources": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Turns out I had the wrong emmet action assigned to the keyboard shortcut I was using, I'd assigned `wrap individual lines with abbreviation` instead of `wrap with abbreviation`